# Is it possible to define a hierarchy to python entry points?

Tags: python

When writing the `setup.py` file there is an option to add entry points in the following format:

```py
entry_points={
    'console_scripts': [
        'entry_point_name0 = module.file:function0',
        'entry_point_name1 = module.file:function1',
        'entry_point_name2 = module.file:function2'
        ]
    }
```

However when doing this, even when all three entry points are from the same project they appear as separate commands in the command line. To execute the first entry point I would simply type `entry_point_name0 <args>` and execute.

**Would it be possible to set up a hierarchy to call those commands by first specifying a common name and later the actual entry point name?** This would result in calling the first entry point using `project_name entry_point_name0 <args>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Just wrote single entry point that would act as a dispatcher.

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('cmd', default='help',
    choices=['help', 'do-good', 'do-evil'],
    help='Command to execute')

args = parser.parse_args()
cmd = args.cmd;

print(f"Your choice is {cmd}")
```

Works like this:

```
$ python cmd.py
usage: cmd.py [-h] {help,do-good,do-evil}
cmd.py: error: the following arguments are required: cmd
$ python cmd.py xyz
usage: cmd.py [-h] {help,do-good,do-evil}
cmd.py: error: argument cmd: invalid choice: 'xyz' (choose from 'help', 'do-good', 'do-evil')
$ python cmd.py do-good
Your choice is do-good
```

You can use `argparse`'s subcommands for this as well: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#sub-commands

Comment: I am using the module click and from your answer I was able to find the same thing for it: https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/5.x/commands/ thanks

Comment: Can you share some pseudo code to explain your answer ?

Comment: @MSS an example added.